# White screen when trying to integrate the flutter with the firebase message ios

Tags: firebase, flutter, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, push

I am trying to integrate the firebase message into my flutter application. On Android it works perfectly, but in Ios, when building the application, it opens a white screen and nothing else appears.

I was able to run the app successfully only once, where a request appeared to receive push messages from the firebase, even until I was able to send a notification.

I uninstalled the app and tried to install again, after that it only stays on a white screen and Ios no longer issues the notification requesting permission to send push.

In X-code Capabilities, I enabled Push Notifications and in Background modes "Background fetch" and "remote notifications"

Has anyone ever experienced this?

Verision:  firebase_messaging: ^5.0.1+1

Main Dart

```
import 'package:App/injection/injector.dart';
import 'package:App/localization/MyLocalizationsDelegate.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:App/pages/home/home.dart';

void main() => runApp(new NewsApp());

class NewsApp extends StatelessWidget {

  MyLocalizationsDelegate myLocation = const MyLocalizationsDelegate();
  FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = new FirebaseMessaging();

  String textToken = 'AQUI VAI O TOKEN';

  NewsApp(){
    Injector.configure(Flavor.PRO);
  }

  @override
  void initState(){
    print('iniciou o initState()');
    firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> msg){
        print('chamou onLaunch');
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> msg){
        print('chamou onResume');
      },
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> msg){
        print('chamou onMessage');
      }
    );
    firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
      const IosNotificationSettings(
        sound: true,
        alert: true,
        badge: true
      )
    );
    firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered.listen((IosNotificationSettings setting) {
      print('Configurações do IOS registradas');
    });
    firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token){
      update(token);
    });
  }
  update(String token){
    print(token);
    textToken = token;
//    setState((){
//
//    });
  }
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    initState();
    return new MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'App',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        primaryColor: Colors.blue,
        accentColor: Colors.blue,
        brightness: Brightness.light
      ),
      supportedLocales: MyLocalizationsDelegate.supportedLocales(),
      localizationsDelegates: [
        myLocation,
        DefaultCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      localeResolutionCallback: myLocation.resolution,
      home: HomePage.create(),
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried running your app on a Simulator, then re-running it on the device, as per this answer ? : https://stackoverflow.com/a/58848088/1290746

Comment: Thank you for your question. I happned it with 6.0.15. Did you resolve?

Answer (score 0):

try to downgrade your firebase_messaging plugin as well as firebase_core

Comment: I already did that too and it did not work. Any specific version to test?

Comment: try this => flutter clean, or try firebase_messaging  3.0.0