# Flutter iOS showing white screen on launch and hang up on that screen

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

## [Flutter iOS app showing white screen on launch and hang up on that screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59661814/flutter-ios-app-showing-white-screen-on-launch-and-hang-up-on-that-screen)

In the default Android emulator it works fine, but when I run it on iOS it shows a white screen

```
fortoers-MBP:ios fortoer$ flutter run
Changing current working directory to: /Users/fortoer/Desktop/Measurements/Flutterapp
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                              3.0s
Upgrading Pods-Runner-frameworks.sh
Running Xcode build...                                                  
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                        11.8s
Xcode build done.                                           74.0s
[VERBOSE-2:FlutterDarwinContextMetalImpeller.mm(37)] Using the Impeller rendering backend.
[VERBOSE-2:FlutterDarwinContextMetalImpeller.mm(37)] Using the Impeller rendering backend.
[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
#0      NotificationHelper.initialize (package:flutter_sixvalley_ecommerce/notification/notification_helper.dart:23:50)
#1      main (package:flutter_sixvalley_ecommerce/main.dart:87:28)
<asynchronous suspension>
Syncing files to device iPhone 12 Pro...                           717ms

Flutter run key commands.
r Hot reload. 
R Hot restart.
h List all available interactive commands.
d Detach (terminate "flutter run" but leave application running).
c Clear the screen
q Quit (terminate the application on the device).

A Dart VM Service on iPhone 12 Pro is available at: http://127.0.0.1:53665/PZkrDfHI4KA=/
The Flutter DevTools debugger and profiler on iPhone 12 Pro is available at:
http://127.0.0.1:9101?uri=http://127.0.0.1:53665/PZkrDfHI4KA=/

fortoers-MBP:ios fortoer$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.6, on macOS 13.4.1 22F770820d darwin-arm64, locale en-SA)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0-rc1)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.82.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] Network resources
```

Answer (score 0):

See if these steps help.
Step1:-Add the flutter Plugin. ...
Step2:-Initialise flutter_native_splash in pubspec.yaml file. ...
Step3:-Customise the settings. ...
Step4:-Run the Package and check the output.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).